# Array subscript out of bouds in an IF statement

Tags: arrays, if-statement, fortran

Below is a section for my code.
The user inputs a value for Energy, if the value is on the array ARRDAT(1,x), then I want it to assign the related variables ARRDAT(2,x), ARRDAT(3,x), and ARRDAT(4,x).

If the data is not on the array, I will interpolate (note: only values between two of my given points will be inputted).

I am able to compile it with a warning

```
warning 179 - Comparning floating point quantities for equality may give misleading results
```

and as soon as I input any value, whether it's in the table or not I get

```
error 11, array subscript(s) out of bounds
```

The error occurs on the line

```
 IF (ARRDAT(1,x) == Energy) THEN
```

I haven't been able to fix it.

```
IMPLICIT NONE
REAL :: Dose, Energy, Source, FeAtt, PbAtt, Resp, Distance, Mu, Thickness
INTEGER :: x, y, upp, low
CHARACTER(LEN=4) :: Material
REAL, PARAMETER :: PI = 3.1415926
real, dimension(1:4,1:25) :: ARRDAT

!Energy MeV
ARRDAT(1,1) = 0.01
ARRDAT(1,2) = 0.015
ARRDAT(1,3) = 0.02
ARRDAT(1,4) = 0.03
ARRDAT(1,5) = 0.04
ARRDAT(1,6) = 0.05
ARRDAT(1,7) = 0.06
ARRDAT(1,8) = 0.08
ARRDAT(1,9) = 0.10
ARRDAT(1,10) = 0.15
ARRDAT(1,11) = 0.20
ARRDAT(1,12) = 0.30
ARRDAT(1,13) = 0.40
ARRDAT(1,14) = 0.50
ARRDAT(1,15) = 0.60
ARRDAT(1,16) = 0.80
ARRDAT(1,17) = 1.0
ARRDAT(1,18) = 1.5
ARRDAT(1,19) = 2.0
ARRDAT(1,20) = 3.0
ARRDAT(1,21) = 4.0
ARRDAT(1,22) = 5.0
ARRDAT(1,23) = 6.0
ARRDAT(1,24) = 8.0
ARRDAT(1,25) = 10.0

!Response Function Sv*cm2
ARRDAT(2,1) = 0.062
ARRDAT(2,2) = 0.157
ARRDAT(2,3) = 0.238
ARRDAT(2,4) = 0.329
ARRDAT(2,5) = 0.365
ARRDAT(2,6) = 0.384
ARRDAT(2,7) = 0.400
ARRDAT(2,8) = 0.451
ARRDAT(2,9) = 0.533
ARRDAT(2,10) = 0.777
ARRDAT(2,11) = 1.03
ARRDAT(2,12) = 1.56
ARRDAT(2,13) = 2.06
ARRDAT(2,14) = 2.54
ARRDAT(2,15) = 2.99
ARRDAT(2,16) = 3.83
ARRDAT(2,17) = 4.60
ARRDAT(2,18) = 6.24
ARRDAT(2,19) = 7.66
ARRDAT(2,20) = 10.2
ARRDAT(2,21) = 12.5
ARRDAT(2,22) = 14.7
ARRDAT(2,23) = 16.7
ARRDAT(2,24) = 20.8
ARRDAT(2,25) = 24.7

!mu/rho for iron cm2/g
ARRDAT(3,1) = 169.4
ARRDAT(3,2) = 56.33
ARRDAT(3,3) = 25.16
ARRDAT(3,4) = 7.891
ARRDAT(3,5) = 3.450
ARRDAT(3,6) = 1.833
ARRDAT(3,7) = 1.113
ARRDAT(3,8) = 0.5391
ARRDAT(3,9) = 0.3340
ARRDAT(3,10) = 0.1786
ARRDAT(3,11) = 0.1357
ARRDAT(3,12) = 0.1051
ARRDAT(3,13) = 0.09131
ARRDAT(3,14) = 0.08241
ARRDAT(3,15) = 0.07583
ARRDAT(3,16) = 0.06631
ARRDAT(3,17) = 0.05951
ARRDAT(3,18) = 0.04863
ARRDAT(3,19) = 0.04254
ARRDAT(3,20) = 0.03616
ARRDAT(3,21) = 0.03309
ARRDAT(3,22) = 0.03144
ARRDAT(3,23) = 0.03056
ARRDAT(3,24) = 0.02991
ARRDAT(3,25) = 0.02994

!mu/rho for lead cm2/g 
ARRDAT(4,1) = 125.7
ARRDAT(4,2) = 108.3
ARRDAT(4,3) = 84.02
ARRDAT(4,4) = 28.94
ARRDAT(4,5) = 13.44
ARRDAT(4,6) = 7.386
ARRDAT(4,7) = 4.531
ARRDAT(4,8) = 2.112
ARRDAT(4,9) = 5.337 
ARRDAT(4,10) = 1.910
ARRDAT(4,11) = 0.9359
ARRDAT(4,12) = 0.3732
ARRDAT(4,13) = 0.2148
ARRDAT(4,14) = 0.1499
ARRDAT(4,15) = 0.1167
ARRDAT(4,16) = 0.08408
ARRDAT(4,17) = 0.06803
ARRDAT(4,18) = 0.05087
ARRDAT(4,19) = 0.04530
ARRDAT(4,20) = 0.04200
ARRDAT(4,21) = 0.04178
ARRDAT(4,22) = 0.04260
ARRDAT(4,23) = 0.04382
ARRDAT(4,24) = 0.04670
ARRDAT(4,25) = 0.04969



WRITE(*,*) 'Please input the particle energy in MeV'
READ(*,*) Energy
x=0
DO x = 0, 25, 1


    IF (ARRDAT(1,x) == Energy) THEN !if the data is already on our table
        ARRDAT(2,x) = Resp
        ARRDAT(3,x) = FeAtt
        ARRDAT(4,x) = PbAtt
        WRITE(*,*) 'CHECK 1'
    ELSE IF (ARRDAT(1,x) < Energy) THEN !if the data is between two points
        upp = x
        low = x - 1
        Energy = ((ARRDAT(1,upp) + ARRDAT(1,low))/2)
        WRITE(*,*) Energy

    ELSE
        WRITE(*,*) 'Invalid Entry'
    END IF

END DO
```

Comment: Please always cipy the comolete output of the program and show how you compile it and which compiler do you use. Do not just select one or two lines with the error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You declare your array to be 1-indexed with `real, dimension(1:4,1:25) :: ARRDAT`, but your `DO` loop begins with `x = 0`, so the first iteration of the loop looks for `ARRDAT(1,0) == Energy`, which is out of bounds.  Start your `DO` loop with `x = 1` and you should be fine.

*Side note*: Fortran automatically indexes arrays beginning with 1, so you can declare your array as `real, dimension(4,25) :: ARRDAT`, and it will have the same effect.

**EDIT**: As mentioned by [@user5713492](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5713492/user5713492) in the comments, this code will still crash if the input `Energy` is greater than `ARRDAT(1,1)`.  You will either have to fix the lower bound of the linear interpolation or skip the interpolation entirely in the first iteration of the loop.  For example:

```
DO x = 1, 25
    IF (ARRDAT(1,x) == Energy) THEN
        ! ...
    ELSE IF (ARRDAT(1,x) < Energy) THEN
        upp = x
        low = x - 1
        IF (low < 1) low = 1  ! <-- make sure we don't go out of bounds on the array
        ! ...
    END IF
END DO
```

... or ...

```
DO x = 1, 25
    IF (ARRDAT(1,x) == Energy) THEN
        ! ...
    ELSE IF (x > 1 .AND. ARRDAT(1,x) < Energy) THEN  ! <-- don't interpolate for the first iteration
        ! ...
    END IF
END DO
```

Now, about that warning concerning comparison of floating point numbers for equality:  please [read this](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) and try to avoid `==`, `>=`, and `<=` operators when comparing `real`s.

Comment: Thank you for the prompt reply and the explanation!

Comment: But the code should still crash when `x = 1` and `Energy > ARRADT(1,1)`.

Comment: Yup--entering a value greater than 0.01 will also lead to a crash.  Good catch.

Comment: A more general remark: it seems possible, just looking at the code, that it may be the O.P.'s first program ever. What is important in programming is to go back and look at the requirements for the assignment and then make sure that they were met, both qualitatively and quantitatively. I am pretty sure that isn't the case for the code given in the original question.